# Can you use "get" in a past tense sentence

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses

I had a voice over where I was asked to record the following line in a script:

"Our small initiative turned into a sizeable movement with the support of influencers, who helped spread the word and get people to make a pledge by greenifying their Facebook profile pictures."

Since the sentence is in past tense, shouldn't "get" be "got"? It felt strange for me to use "get" instead of "got". When I raised the question, the copy writer said it's like saying: "who helped get people..." Now that sounds correct in that case. Thank you for anyone who can explain and clarify this for me.

Comment: Your copywriter seems to be right considering what influencers are supposed to do (whatever it means). They help spread the word, they help get people to make a pledge.

Comment: Your copywriter had a point. There's nothing ungrammatical about using past tense "got", but it's less jarring if the coordinated complement clauses of past tense "helped" are both infinitivals: _helped [spread the word] and [get people to make a pledge ...]_.

Comment: Your copywriter had a point. There's nothing ungrammatical about using past tense "got", but it's less jarring to have two coordinated infinitival clauses as catenative complements of "helped" rather than one catenative complement and one finite clause.

Answer (score 7):

"**Spread**" and "**get**" are *infinitives*, so not in the present tense, and they should stay that way => **to help + inf**. Your sentence can indeed be read that way:

> "who **helped spread** the word and **helped get** people to..."

Comment: "helped spread the word and get people to make a pledge" and "helped spread the word and got people to make a pledge" are both perfect English. They just mean different things.

Comment: Indeed they do, but in this particular context and punctuation, the first one is the one intended.

Comment: Not if one is a rational and reasonable human being. Any brag is then always about something already achived, thus, the latter one is the only possible outcome.

Comment: I would argue that it's up to the writer to tell me, the reader, what was meant: did *he help spread the word and help get people to sign up*, or did *he help spread the word and also got people to sign up*? Or would you say that *he helped spread the word, getting people to sign up*? Ah, language... :)

Comment: @ProfYaffle, it's a good thing, then, that the OP in fact *asked* the writer what was meant and reported his response.  Morgan's is the only plausible analysis I see that is consistent with that response.

Comment: @PellMel Understood - "helped spread... and helped get" does seem to be the intent, no argument. My point is that it remains a little ambiguous, and the copywriter should perhaps rephrase - but it's hard to conclude that he "helped spread... and got", because he wasn't acting alone, and was assisting in that task versus completing it alone.

Answer (score 2):

*Get* and *got* both work here but require the sentence to be parsed differently.

What your copy-writer apparently intended was for the sentence to be parsed like this:

> Our small initiative turned into a sizeable movement with the support of influencers, who helped
> *(a)* **spread** the word
> and [helped]
> *(b)* **get** people to make a pledge by greenifying their Facebook profile pictures.

With this parsing, *get* is the correct form, namely a bare infinitive parallel to *spread.* In your first approach to the sentence, however, you succumbed to the temptation to parse it thus:

> Our small initiative turned into a sizeable movement with the support of influencers, who
> *(a)* **helped** spread the word
> and [who]
> *(b)* **got** people to make a pledge by greenifying their Facebook profile pictures.

With this second parsing, *got* would indeed be the correct form, namely a simple-past indicative parallel to *helped.* The copy-writer apparently did not intend this second parsing and failed to appreciate how tempting it is. This failure is thoroughly normal: when we have just recently written a sentence we know what we meant and parse accordingly, but a careful writer makes extra effort to assure that a reader will, on the first try, parse as intended (or as *needed,* which may not be exactly the same thing—more on that anon).

For this purpose, one good approach is to reread one’s sentence after the passage of some days, and so discover the trap by tripping on it, after which one can correct or defuse it. If time does not permit that, one may show the copy to someone else (such as a wonderfully intelligent voice-over person), pay attention to that person’s mis-parsings, and then reword so as to prevent them. Best of all, one should learn to reread one’s copy, however soon after writing it, as if one had never encountered it before.

The syntactic booby-trap in the present sentence could be defused by simply changing the bare infinitives to *to* infinitives (which are a little wordier but perfectly acceptable here) in order to make this less of a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence):

> Our small initiative turned into a sizeable movement with the support of influencers, who helped *to* spread the word and *to* get people to make a pledge by greenifying their Facebook profile pictures.

One disadvantage here, though, is the stacking of *to*-infinitives: *to get* people *to make.* That’s a bit ugly. But frankly I fail to see why your copy-writer’s intended parsing is in any way preferable to yours. To get people to do something and to *help* get people to do something are finally not very different in meaning. So why not just go with the second parsing and use *got?* Sometimes one’s reader, following the garden path, winds up with a *better* sentence than one originally intended, and the wise writer will humbly embrace that one.

Comment: Because it's less 'jarring' to the listener if the coordinated complements of "help" are both infinitival catenatives.

Comment: @BillJ, but your proffered reason *presupposes* the first parsing, which is [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: Not at all; I'm simply stating that I prefer a coordination of two infinitivals rather than one infinitival and one preterite. That contrast is the entire issue at hand.

Comment: No one is coordinating an infinitival with a preterite here; with the second parsing, the parallelism is between two preterites, *helped* and *got.*

Comment: Sorry, I was being sloppy. The OP's preferred analysis is a coordination of two preterite VPs _helped spread the word_ and _got people to make ..._. But I prefer the coordination to be of two non-finite (catenative) complements of "helped", i.e. _influencers helped [spread the word] and [get people to make ...]_.

Comment: Watch out! FrankSixteen is coming to get you!

Answer (score 1):

> Since the sentence is in past tense, shouldn't "get" be "got"?

The word "got" is indeed the simple past tense of "to get", but you need to analyze the sentence a bit more deeply.  How is "get" used there?  In fact, it is the bare infinitive, as @MorganFR observed.  Infinitives function as nouns, and do not change tense.  The verb in the sentence is ***helped***, which you will recognize is indeed in the past tense.  The construction used means the same as "they helped spread the word, and they helped ***get*** people to greenify."

There is nevertheless some room for confusion: if there were a comma before the "and" then the rest of the sentence would be interpreted as an independent clause with an implied subject.  In that case, "got" would be correct; the meaning would be the same as "they helped spread the word, and they ***got*** people to greenify."

That subtle difference is of particular import to a person such as yourself, who is in the business of recording voice overs.  The version with the comma would ordinarily be read with a slight pause at the comma position, and the presence or absence of that pause will affect how listeners will perceive the second part of the sentence.

Comment: What a load of nonsense. The only thing that matters is what meaning you want to communicate. Are you refering to greenifying that happend before then past tense GOT is correct. On the other hand, if you're refering to upcomming greeifying GET is correct.

Comment: Yet another very aggressive comment... Besides, PellMel is right. Grammar has rules.

Comment: PellMel has not even made a reasonable argument to support his point. Only some vague rant about how infinitives functions as nouns and some other crap that doesn't hold a root searching explanation. My argument is naked and extremely easy to undertand. I say it is all about what you are refering to. If you are refering to past time, then past tense. There is not a single angle to attack this argument.

Comment: The sentence requires a past tense indeed, and that is exactly what is used: "help**ed** spread". Moreover, if a verb follows "help", the infinitive form *must* be used. How is that for an angle?

Comment: "helped" is only refering to "spread". "Get" is refering to "make a pledge". They are two different things in the communication and both can have happend at different times. We cannot know that from the sentence if we do not agree upon what tense is used is telling something about when it happend or will happen.

Comment: @FrankSixteen, I acknowledge that there is a bit of ambiguity in the original sentence, and that "get" could conceivably be interpreted in the present tense as an ongoing activity of the influencers.  The OP makes clear that that was not the intent of the copywriter, however.  If the whole sentence is therefore taken as retrospective then its actual structure affords only the interpretation I presented: the verb "helped" has two objects joined by "and", each one a verb phrase with a bare infinitive.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207620/whats-the-difference-between-the-infinitive-bare-infinitive-and-base-form.  Also http://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/.

Comment: It doesn't matter what was the intention of the copywriter. Language stands on its own feets. A rational human being does not brag about something yet to have been achived, thus "got" is a given. Still I hold the door wide open for they who prefer "get" and be irrational. A last thing. Don't think for a second I do not recognize the spectatular movement everybody has taken toward my standing. It all started with a claim the language itself demands "get". Now everybody understands how wrong this is. Kind of funny. English is my ninth languge and I'm the one teaching you and correctly.